# How to type # in math mode?

Tags: math-mode

How to type this symbol
[image]

in math mode?

I googled it, but I got nothing;(

Comment: That's just `\#`.

Comment: load the "mathabx" package, and then write "\hash" or "\varhash" in math mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This mostly depends on what kind of symbol you need. If it's an ordinary symbol, just

```
\#
```

will do, using the hash symbol from the main text font. But if you need a relation symbol or an operation symbol, you need, respectively

```
\mathrel\#
\mathbin\#
```

Note the difference:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$a \# b$

$a \mathrel\# b$

$a \mathbin\# b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The difference between the last two is subtle, but noticeable.

Of course, the best is, after you have decided the type, to define your command, for instance

```
\newcommand{\mathhash}{\mathrel\#}
```

Choose a more semantic name.

You might want to import `\hash` from `mathabx`. Here I define a `\mathrel`, change to `\mathord` or `\mathbin` if you want an ordinary or operation symbol respectively.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{matha}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{matha}{m}{n}{
 <-5.5> matha5
 <5.5-6.5> matha6
 <6.5-7.5> matha7
 <7.5-8.5> matha8
 <8.5-9.5> matha9
 <9.5-11> matha10
 <11-> matha12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{matha}{U}{matha}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\hash}{\mathrel}{matha}{"23}


\begin{document}

$a \hash b$

\end{document}
```

[image]